# How can different people track changes in the unprotected text form fields?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, forms, tracking

I am working on a protected word 2007 form. How can different people track changes in the unprotected text form fields? The text appears in black and changing the track changes option doesn't change the color of the text. I am hoping that different users can select a text color and edit text in each of the form fields.

Thanks!

Comment: Is change tracking activated when users fill in the form fields? Does the color change when you change the text in the form field AND tracking is activated?

Comment: Dude, if you want our help, you'll have to give us some more info.